# How to draw sprites at the right position

Tags: libgdx, sprite

I'm getting crazy trying to understand libgdx's system coordinates.
I've made a grid of containers (classes that extend Container, and have a reference to their screen position with a Vector2) in the center of my stage. Now, when the user clicks on any of these slots, he can add an actor (which has a Sprite) to it. The first thing that my Actors need to do is initialize his Sprite.

The first thing to which a normal guy thiks is "ok, i have to set the position of the Sprite. I can take the reference to the position (Vector2) of its Container and use that position for my Sprite"

So, i did that:

```
@Override
protected void initActor() {
    Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("blue_square.png"));
    sprite = new Sprite(texture, texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
    sprite.setPosition(getSlotActor().getPosition().x, getSlotActor().getPosition().y);
}
```

My grid is 5x5. If i click on the middle row, the Sprite happens to be in the right position, if i click on the 2nd row, it happears on the fourth one, if i click on the first row it happears on the fifth one, if i click on the fifth one it happears on the first one and so on...

I can't understand this behavior..

Answer (score 0):

To quote from the [docs on Mouse & touch](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Mouse,-touch-%26-keyboard#mouse--touch) (my emphasis):

> ... input mechanisms report the location of interaction as 2D
>   coordinates relative to the **upper left corner** of the screen, with the
>   positive x-axis pointing to the right and the **y-axis pointing**
>   **downward**.

So, from the behavior you're describing it seems you are expecting the y-axis to point upward from the lower left corner, when in reality the y-axis points downward from the upper left corner.

The fix is rather easy: Reverse the y-axis you get from the touch event by subtracting the y-axis from the screen height:

```
int float real_y_axis = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - touch_y_axis;
```